# Problems with density calculation of cdplot() in R

Tags: r, density-plot

(Not sure whether this question belongs to CrossValidated or Stackoverflow)

Subset of my data:

```
mdat1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Bilbao", 
"San Sebastian", "Vitoria"), class = "factor"), PrecipTotal = c(0, 
1.01600203200406, 0, 6.09601219202438, 73.4061468122936, 4.31800863601727, 
0, 0.254000508001016, 7.8740157480315, 5.58801117602235, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2.03200406400813, 0, 0.254000508001016, 0, 2.03200406400813, 
0, 0, 0, 57.9121158242316, 1.77800355600711, 0, 0.762001524003048, 
6.3500127000254, 0, 0, 1.27000254000508, 8.89001778003556, 1.01600203200406, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762001524003048, 0, 8.89001778003556, 0, 0, 21.8440436880874, 
0, 0.508001016002032, 0, 0.508001016002032, 0.508001016002032, 
0, 0, 0, 14.4780289560579, 0.254000508001016, 0.508001016002032, 
0, 23.3680467360935, 6.09601219202438, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.1940563881128, 
0, 0, 0, 3.04800609601219, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.09601219202438, 0, 2.03200406400813, 
0, 4.06400812801626, 0, 0.508001016002032, 0, 0, 0.508001016002032, 
7.11201422402845, 34.0360680721361, 0, 0, 0, 7.8740157480315, 
0, 4.06400812801626, 0, 0, 0.508001016002032, 5.08001016002032, 
7.11201422402845, 7.11201422402845, 0, 0, 0, 1.01600203200406, 
0, 0, 0), Hail = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hail", 
"NoHail"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "PrecipTotal", 
"Hail"), row.names = c(43878L, 33821L, 40681L, 35121L, 45112L, 
46428L, 45844L, 43199L, 34440L, 43184L, 32850L, 39220L, 38416L, 
33860L, 34867L, 32737L, 43232L, 31772L, 35850L, 38894L, 39289L, 
33148L, 32159L, 43197L, 43962L, 45068L, 41848L, 35929L, 34842L, 
42069L, 39503L, 31747L, 43286L, 34919L, 43925L, 45368L, 42489L, 
41686L, 43194L, 34747L, 37001L, 42923L, 45006L, 46170L, 33191L, 
34392L, 44047L, 35859L, 42159L, 38843L, 45860L, 34180L, 33846L, 
42810L, 46160L, 33523L, 34840L, 40226L, 42868L, 43576L, 46570L, 
39980L, 42453L, 42063L, 38121L, 32822L, 40670L, 32859L, 46228L, 
40239L, 32420L, 38874L, 39638L, 39523L, 31765L, 32753L, 33752L, 
35574L, 36263L, 32871L, 32539L, 38455L, 41119L, 45124L, 34560L, 
34144L, 41461L, 41449L, 35499L, 42783L, 34106L, 38151L, 36313L, 
46593L, 39973L, 43928L, 35240L, 43626L, 46195L, 44388L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the following code

```
cdplot(mdat1 [, 2], mdat1 [, 3], ylab = "", main = "1", 
                 xlab = "", 
                 col = c("purple", "gray"))
```

creates a messed up output (**"1"**) of `cdplot()`. Using a different sample of my original data produces the output labeled with **"2"**

[image]

I assume that it has something to do with the distribution of the x-values? If they are extremely skewed (like for "1"), the density calculation gets in trouble?

[image]

Comment: you might consider posting chart 1 to [here](http://accidental-art.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it was simply a bug, albeit one that you are warned rather vaguely about when the help page says "conditional densities are more reliable for high-density regions of x". Contrast all these efforts with the result you get with lattice's `densityplot`. (Much cleaner and informative in my opinion.) The `cdplot` and `ggplot` efforts appear to seriously distort the data.

```
library(lattice)
densityplot(~PrecipTotal, groups=Hail, mdat1, col = c("purple", "gray"))
```

You can contrast that disply of the data with the output from that less pathological appearance you get from:

```
cdplot(Hail ~ PrecipTotal, data=mdat1, bw=2)
```

... but that still leaves you with the impression that there is substantial difference in the densities of the two groups in the region of 45-65 whereas the side-by-side display should you htat there is a gap in one and a single point in the other group which seems far more easily explained by random variation.

[image]

There is the fine point to be made that the lattice plotting argument convention is that separate plots result from a formula specification that includes the grouping variable, whereas bringing the grouping in with the `groups=` mechanism includes them in the same plot region.

Comment: Thx for this explanation. The data I provided ist just a random subset showing the same error I face with my large DF (7k obs.). So the problem with the single point between 45-65 is just due to randomness of the subset. However, this problem may also occur in my acutal data. The lattice approach is nice, thanks for showing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it looks when I simply adjust the `bw` parameter without modifying your data, so I would say just play with the `bw` parameter.

```
cdplot(mdat1 [, 2], mdat1 [, 3], ylab = "", 
              xlab = "", 
              col = c("purple", "gray"), bw = 1)
```

[image]

```
cdplot(mdat1 [, 2], mdat1 [, 3], ylab = "", 
              xlab = "", 
              col = c("purple", "gray"), bw = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Both plots seriously misrepresent the data and the second one is potentially more serious because it does not give you any warnings about the fact that the broad purple band between 45 and 65 is based on a single point.

Comment: @42- Agreed. I am just trying to show him how he can get an unscrewed plot from the data he has, sort of.

Comment: Simple solution, did not consider this. I´ll check this out on my actual data. Strengthening my assumption that the problem is due to distribution of my data in combination with forced "binwidth" pressure. @42- also pointed to the statement of the help page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to consider transforming your `PrecipTotal` variable first, then create a conditional density plot. After monkeying around a bit, it seems like taking the `sqrt` of the variable might be sufficient. We may also need to adjust the `binwidth` to get a better looking plot.

Obviously, these transformations and adjustment require us to be very careful about our interpretation of the relationship.

### Base `R` using `cdplot`

```
cdplot(Hail ~ sqrt(PrecipTotal), data = mdat1)
```

[image]

### `ggplot2` using `geom_density` and `position = 'fill'`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mdat1, aes(sqrt(PrecipTotal)))+
    geom_density(aes(fill = Hail), position = 'fill')+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

### `ggplot2` with some options

```
ggplot(mdat1, aes(sqrt(PrecipTotal)))+
    geom_density(aes(fill = Hail), position = 'fill',
                 kernel = 'cosine', adjust = 1.1)+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: You´re right, data transformation is probably one solution if the problem is caused by the distribution of the data. I agree on the interpretation problems afterwards. Thanks for showing the approach in ggplot2!